# Workaround for z-index issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

[image]

How to bring the red div on top of the blue div?

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v223fapy/) of this problem.

The images inside the `#greendiv` in the fiddle should also come over the `#reddiv` when dragged.

Comment: where's the fiddle?

Comment: The question is somewhat different then your fiddle. `Z-index` is not going to do what you ask. The blue `div` is always on top or below the green `div`, and the red `div` is inside the green `div`. You can not put the blue `div` between the green and red.

Answer (score 2):

▶ It's impossible to put a **`div`** in between a **`parent`** and a **`child`** if that **`div`** is not a child itself, because the **`z-index`** properties of the two elements *(**`red`** and **`blue`** in your case)* are of different climax.

Setting **`z-index: 9999`** for  **`red`**, you just make sure that **`red`**, will be stacked on top of everything inside **`green`**, but you don't influence in any way anything outside of it *(**`blue`**)*.

**Here's a quick image I made illustrating this point:**
[image]

---

▶ To solve the problem with the image-dragging in your jsfiddle, however, you can make your images come over **`#reddiv`** by putting:

```
img {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

***Beware:*** For the above to work, **`#greendiv`** must have the same or greater **`z-index`** than **`#reddiv`**, because as said above, no matter how high you set the **`z-index`** of the child *(images)*, it will never stack higher than another element which is not its sibling *(**`#reddiv`**)*.

---

**jsFiddle:** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v223fapy/6/).

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#greendiv img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
});
```

```css
#reddiv,
#greendiv {
  width: 100px;          /* I made them 100px to */
  height: 100px;         /*  fit in the snippet  */
  position: relative;
}

#greendiv {
  background: green;
}

#reddiv {
  background: red;
}

img {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="greendiv">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/30x40" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/30x40" />
</div>

<div id="reddiv"></div>
```

---

[Here](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) is a great article about **`z-index`** suggested by *@JohnDetlefs*.

Comment: A good article on this can be found here --> https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: @JohnDetlefs a great article indeed.

Answer (score 0):

just add `z-index:-1` to the `#reddiv` and `z-index:1` to the `#greendiv`

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v223fapy/4/)**

```
#greendiv {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}

#reddiv {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the z-index more than both of boxes as if you set the z-index for green 1, then for blue it should be 2 and for the red it should be 3.